# lambda java amazon linux os

Tags: java, aws-lambda

I am uploading a java 8 function on lambda but the libs are taking a huge place.

Each lib is duplicated for specific os:

- *-linux-x86.jar
- *-linux-x86_64.jar
- *-linux-armhf.jar
- *-linux-arm64.jar

I could take only one to get a lighter package but I can not found which one I have to take for aws lambda with java 8

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) should help then.

Comment: I already had a look, but I can only see Amazon Linux, and I can not find more details

Comment: If you look closely, you might notice 100% of those Amazon Linux versions end in "x86_64". And 0% of them end in "x86" or "arm*". You can make custom images. And I would expect a "x86" custom image would work. But I have no idea if they even support arm for custom images.

Comment: @Ajouve do you still need help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java Lambda runtime supports following [architectures](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html):

| Name | Identifier | Architecture |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Java 11 | `java11` | x86_64, arm64 |
| Java 8 | `java8.a12` | x86_64, arm64 |
| Java 8 | `java8` | x86_64 |

So you would only have to package either *x86_64* or the *arm64* libs.

> Lambda functions that use arm64 architecture (AWS Graviton2 processor) can achieve significantly better price and performance than the equivalent function running on x86_64 architecture. Consider using arm64 for compute-intensive applications such as high-performance computing, video encoding, and simulation workloads. [Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/foundation-arch.html#foundation-arch-adv)

Depending on which architecture you want to use, you only have to package the libs for that architecture. You can deploy your Lambda function either as zip file and configure the architecture used in the Lambda function's settings or [create a Lambda function from a container image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-images.html)